# Time series with zero-values

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have a daily time series about the sales of a product, my series start from 01/01/2016 until 31/08/2017.

There is something important about this series, it does have zero-values each Sunday because this shop doesn't work on Sundays, and it will not work on Sundays in the future, so I the expected value for Sundays is zero.

Once I run an Arima model, I am not sure about this forecast, I think it is not working but I do not know why.

I really need help here !

This is my data

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzIf8XvzKOGWSm1ucUdYUVhfVGs/view?usp=sharing

This is my code

> x <- read.table("Series.txt", header = TRUE)
>
> attach(x)
>
> library(zoo)
>
> myzoo<-zoo(x, seq(from = as.Date("2016-01-01"), to = as.Date("2017-08-31"), by = "day"))
>
> plot(myzoo)
>
> fit<-auto.arima(myzoo)
>
> p1=forecast(fit,30)
>
> plot(p1)

And this is my forecast

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo5C7.png)

As you can see, I feel I'm doing something wrong, but I just do not know what.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Shouldn't Sunday be a `NA` rather than zero?

Answer (score 1):

## Approach 1:

Just set the Sunday observations to `NA`s. You can then replace the Sunday forecasts with 0s.

## Approach 2:

Remove the Sundays and define the week as 6-days in length.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!. But I do not know how to define the week as 6-days, could you tell me please how can I do that ? , thank you so much